# Finding book: Small space-traveling crew make/sell drug and a creature begin linking people's drug dream together

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

Unfortunately, I can't recall when I read this story, what timeframe it was authored, or who the author may have been. But I can remember enough key information from the story I think someone familiar should recognize it:

- Small space-travelling crew (2 women and 1 man I think) that produce and spread a drug (named "Blue?" - not sure).
- Drug is highly addictive and puts people into a peaceful dream-like state where they are entirely alone. (At least one individual describes their dream as standing on a bridge watching fish swimming in the water below.)
- The drug-dealing crew have access to old nano-technology they use while on planets for surveillance/(defense?) and each have some sort of virtual environment to selves on the ship.
- On a planet they find some slug-type lifeform and their nano-environment starts behaving strangely. And the crew's virtual world-spaces also start to mess up and allow the individuals to enters others' spaces.
- The younger woman on the crew (and considered least valuable), through trickery, ends up pregnant due to one of the slugs having been slipped inside her without her knowledge.
- The slugs also end up addicted to the drug when it is dumped in a crate with a bunch inside.
- Addicts of the drug reveal that they are beginning to see other people inside the dream-world.
- The child the younger crew-member has from the slug ends up treated something like a god by the addicts because it can bring them all together in their dream.
- I think there was some Eve and the Apple type metaphors going in the story.

Hope this is enough for someone to help me find it again. It was a really odd read, but interesting and I'd like to re-fill in the blanks I've developed.